# suggest something else for g suggest something else for g suggest something else for g

Tags: css, loops, sass

I wrote this mixin but it is looping so much time. Can you help me to optimize my code or can you suggest something else for getting the desired result?

```
<div class='mh-60 pt-10'>dfgdfgsdfgsdf</div>
```

Comment: In most cases the key to optimization is to reduce amount of loops.

You could easily move the generation of 'top, bottom, left, right' to the bottom loop - reducing entire code ot a single loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you're looking for.

```
$spaces: (4, 8, 10, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 40, 44, 50, 52, 60);

@each $space in $spaces {
  @each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m, padding: p) {
    @each $side, $infix in (top: t, bottom: b, left: l, right: r) {
      .#{$abbrev}#{$infix}-#{$space} {
        #{$prop}-#{$side}: #{$space}px;
      }
    }
  }
}

@each $space in $spaces {
  @each $prop, $abbrev in (margin: m, padding: p) {
    .#{$abbrev}v-#{$space} {
        #{$prop}-top: #{$space}px;
        #{$prop}-bottom: #{$space}px;
    }

    .#{$abbrev}h-#{$space} {
        #{$prop}-left: #{$space}px;
        #{$prop}-right: #{$space}px;
    }
  }
}
```